# Determining polarity of high voltage spark generator

Tags: high-voltage, polarity

I have a piezo ignition spark generator (Gasmate GMPIK-1) and I want to know the direction the current flows. I can't exactly hook it up to my multimeter because the spark  only lasts for a fraction of a second and is approximately 20,000 volts (it can produce a spark of about 1 cm.) How can I determine the polarity of this igniter?

If I were to try running it through a diode I am worried I would just ruin the diode.

[image: Igniter in question]

Comment: For fun, also look [here](https://youtu.be/HupFY_24o-4). That may provide something to consider, further and it gets at some of the basics.

Comment: It is AC. Pushing is one polarity, releasing is another. And fading oscillating.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a 100k resistor in series to a small 1uf capacitor.

The resistor will limit the current spike and voltage and the capacitor will store some of that power, you can then measure the residual voltage at the cap lead.

If it's too low, gradually reduce the resistor value.

Comment: You might add a schematic to be completely clear, I can think of at mleast three ways to connect a series resistor and capacitor to a piezo and DMM, and two of them won;t do what's wanted. The third one is better described by 'lowpass filter' than 'series connection'.